# What API do I require to use this method in Java?

Tags: java, api

I tried importing the following APIs to use this method but for some reason, it Java does not recognize this method.

```
  import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

  import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;  

  StringEntity(payload,ContentType.create("application/json");
```

Here is the complete Java code:

```
public void testCustomerApiIsExposed() throws JSONException {

    try {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost p = new HttpPost("http://myURL");



        String payload = "{id:\"" + 1 + "\","  + "method:\"" + "customerApi.getApiToken" + "\", params [\"DELETED\", \"DELETED\", \"\", \"\", \"\",\"\", \"\", false, \"\", \"\"" + "]}";


        /*What API do I need to import for this method???????*/
        p.setEntity(new StringEntity( payload,

        ContentType.create("application/json"))); 

        HttpResponse r = c.execute(p);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {

            builder.append(line).append("\n");

        }

        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener("[" + builder.toString() +"]");

        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);

        JSONObject o = finalResult.getJSONObject(0);

        String apiToken = (String) o.get("result");

    }

    catch(IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }

}
```

Can someone guide me here? Thanks

Comment: Post the full java file here

Comment: `import` statements have to be declared at the top of the file and this method seems to be just floating somewhere. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I know that! I posted here in the question for better understanding. Let me edit if it creates ambiguity.

Comment: In case [`StringEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.http.entity.ContentType%29) is the one from Apache it would need the apache `ContentType` - to use either of them you'll have to have the [Apache HTTP](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html) [library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/download.html).

Comment: You need [http core](http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0/httpcore-4.0.jar.html) library

Answer (score 0):

The class `javax.mail.internet.ContentType` does not have a `create` method. Only `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType` has it.

The compiler resolved the package to `javax.mail.internet`. To remove the ambiguity, explicitly mention the package:

```
StringEntity(payload,org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create("application/json");
```

If your issue is on `StringEntity`, you need [Apache HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). To date, the latest version is HttpCore 4.3.1.

Comment: Fine.I did that what you have posted here. But even then Java says: "Remove argument to match StringEntity(String)". So is it a constructor issue? In my code I am using StringEntity(String string, ContentType contentType). Kindly update. Thanks